# Finding strings not %in% other vector of strings

Tags: r

If you have a vector of strings and you want to know which match. It's a simple matter of using %in%.

```
x <- c("red","blue","green")
y <- c("yellow","blue","orange")

which(x %in% y) # Literally, which X are in Y.
```

But what about the opposite, where you would like to find which X are not in Y?

Comment: Try `which(!x %in% y)`.

Comment: Roman add it as a solution

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I was using `which(is.na(match(x,y))` it just seemed too ugly.

Comment: You know what they say, there's a 100 ways to skin a cat. :)

Comment: Another "ugly" way is: `as.vector(na.action(na.omit(match(x,y))))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A neat way that I like (that I learnt from @joran, iirc) is:

```
`%nin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
which(x %nin% y)
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: `%nin%` is also provided by the `Hmisc` package, among others.

Comment: +1 to Arun for going the extra mile/kilometer.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I suggest you accept this is the correct answer, it's more general.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

Doing `%in%` returns a vector of trues and falses. Using an exclamation mark will turn those Ts and Fs around, and by wrapping everything in `which` will give you indices.

```
> which(!x %in% y)
[1] 1 3
> which(x %in% y)
[1] 2
```

Comment: Also, if you are going to do `x[which(!x %in% y)]`, then you might prefer `setdiff(x, y)`. The latter is also applying `unique`.

Comment: I may be paranoid, but I'd humbly suggest `which(!(x %in% y))`, to improve readability.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft I agree with you and I like the parenthesis too.  However, that's one more reason why the `%ni%` suggestion below is so great!